# Duplicate class android.support.v13.view.**

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, sdk, build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {


    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion = '32.1.0 rc1'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.andrd_ado_vdo_tkbk_demo"
        minSdkVersion 17
//        minSdkVersion 14 the emoji lib will not work
        //minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 30
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode 1
        versionName "2022.01.09"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        buildTypes {
            debug {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:2.0.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.12.2'

    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'io.paperdb:paperdb:2.7.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.8.0'
    implementation 'io.nlopez.smartlocation:library:3.3.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'

    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.4.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.4.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:11.4.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.4.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.4.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:11.4.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.4.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:11.4.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:11.4.2'
    implementation 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.9.1.0'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.miguelcatalan:materialsearchview:1.4.0'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.rxrelay:rxrelay:1.2.0'
    testImplementation('junit:junit:4.12')
    implementation project(':emoticon')
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I'm facsing this error whenever I try to run my android application:

Duplicate class android.support.v13.view.DragAndDropPermissionsCompat found in modules support-compat-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0) and support-v13-25.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-v13:25.0.0) Duplicate class android.support.v13.view.DragStartHelper found in modules support-compat-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0) and support-v13-25.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-v13:25.0.0) ..etc

I'm not sure what is the source of these errors since i'm not using any of these libraries. initially I had more of these errors but then removed the following:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.0.0'
```